# How to get data from a command run in a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I fixed the previous problem I had with the function, but now I'm not sure how to get the changed variables from the function to change the label.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import random

def testTrue(firstNo,secondNo):
    if firstNo + secondNo == int(entry1.get()):
        firstNo = random.randint(1,15)
        secondNo = random.randint(1,15)
        problem = ("What is",firstNo,"+",secondNo)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Answer", "Correct")
    elif firstNo + secondNo != entry1.get():
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Answer", "Wrong, try again!")

main = Tk()

entryType = IntVar()

firstNo = random.randint(1,15)
secondNo = random.randint(1,15)
problem = ("What is",firstNo,"+",secondNo)

label1 = Label(main,text=problem).grid(row=0, sticky=E)
entry1 = Entry(main,textvariable=entryType)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1)

submitButton = Button(main,text="Submit",command=lambda: testTrue(firstNo,secondNo)).grid(columnspan=2,row=2)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: returning a value from callback is meaningless since there is nothing to return to. You'll need global variables or class structre to save/use those values.

Comment: @Lafexlos could you give me an example of using that with a class or global variable?